# Error migrating app from angular 13 to angular 14. Type 'AbstractControl<never, never>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormArray<any>'

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular14

After migrating an app from Angular 13, to Angular 14, several errors have appeared in the console when I run `npm start`:

First error:

```
error TS2352: Conversion of type 'AbstractControl<never, never>' to
type 'FormArray<any>' may be a mistake because neither type
sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert
the expression to 'unknown' first.

const statusArray = filterForm.get('status').get('value') as FormArray;
```

Here is the code:

```
const filterForm = new FormGroup({});
const filters = portcallFilter;
Object.keys(filters)
  .filter((item) => isNaN(Number(item)))
  .forEach((i) => {        
      filterForm.registerControl(
        i,
        this.formBuilder.group({
          value: '',
          comparison: filters[i],
        })
      );        
  });
const statusArray = filterForm.get('status').get('value') as FormArray;
```

I have more or less the same issue in other components:

Second error:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(name: "query", control: FormControl<string>): FormControl<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"query"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(this: FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>, name: string, control: AbstractControl<any, any>): AbstractControl<any, any>', gave the following error.
    The 'this' context of type 'FormGroup<{ query: FormControl<string>; }>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'FormGroup<{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }>'.
      Property 'query' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }' but required in type '{ query: FormControl<string>; }'
```

The code is:

```
public searchForm = new FormGroup({
    query: new FormControl(this.inputSearch ?? ''),
  });

applyFilters(filters: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string }[] }): void {
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((fil) => {
      this.searchForm.registerControl(
        fil,
        new FormControl(this.filtersValues?.[fil] ?? '')
      );
    });
  }
```

Third error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'FormGroup<{ a: FormControl<string>; b: FormControl<string>; c: FormControl<string>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl<unknown>'.
  Type 'FormGroup<{ a: FormControl<string>; b: FormControl<string>; disclaimer: c<string>; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<unknown>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

const shipList = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    pda.shipList?.forEach((item) => {
      shipList.push(
        this.formBuilder.group({
          a: item.a,
          b: item.b,
          c: item.c,
        })
      );
    });
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler states, you have an issue of type compatibility. Angular 14 introduced **Strongly Typed Forms** to the `Forms` API. This allows for better Developer Experience (The intention is not to cause problems in your code and make your life harder). The **Strongly Typed Forms** allow you to catch runtime bugs at compile time, making your life easier down the road. They also help a lot when it comes to property inference with language services integration in your IDE.

You have two ways to solve this:

1- Define a data model and supply it to the strongly typed form ([read here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms))

2- Use Untyped Forms option for migration from V13 to V14 ([read here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#automated-untyped-forms-migration))

Comment: Thank you so much. Untyped Forms did the trick. Much appreciated :)